# API design - json_api best practice to return no data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api-design, json-api

I have Rails app that also has an API. I've been trying to follow http://jsonapi.org for the overall structure, but I can't find any guidelines for when it comes to result without any data. I for example have an endpoint that looks like this:

```
https://[root]/api/apps/34/localized_strings?from_date=1330776000
```

Where `from_date` is a unix timestamp, if the server have updated or newer data based on this date value I return all the data, it there a no updates I want to return no data. And I wonder what's the best way for doing this is. The current result looks like this:

```
{
  "data": []
}
```

Would it be better or more conventional based on http://jsonapi.org to instead return a status of "status": `204` in cases where there are no changes or data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-resources), a response representing an empty collection would be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles"
  },
  "data": []
}
```

A server **MUST** respond to a successful request to fetch an individual resource with a resource object or `null` provided as the response document’s primary data.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
  },
  "data": null
}
```

Comment: This is not correct.  Assuming by 'no data' OP means empty body, then http://stackoverflow.com/a/37521258/879854 is correct: 204 status, no body, no content type. If OP means no primary resources is expected, then, the data element may be omitted. A success document must have ONE OF data, errors, or meta.  So, response body could be just meta or meta and maybe some others

Comment: If this is a GET to a resource, then data: null makes sense: "fetch an individual resource with a resource object or null provided as the response document’s primary data"

Comment: Since this request may be interpreted as a conditional get, then the response would be an empty body and 304 https://httpstatuses.com/304

Comment: The OP is not talking about general JSON API design, in which I would agree to return the 204 status code. He is talking about the JSONAPI specification, which is an opinionated specification for building APIs in JSON. I just quoted the specification, therefore my answer is correct.

Comment: yeah, that's why I commented two more times (I couldn't edit).  You're right that your answer is valid JSON API.  In the end, OP, I think, needs to decide on what the response is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 3):

Just return `head :no_content`, so rails will return 204 status code with empty content

Here is an example for destroy

```
def destroy
  # Destroy stuff

  # Return 204, no content
  head :no_content
end
```